# How to get breakpoint into NotificationServiceExtension?

Tags: ios, swift, remote-notifications, notificationservices

Is it possible to get debug point into NotificationServiceExtension when app is into killed mode.

actually what i suppose to achieved is that saved remote notification data into database but in some random cases data not saved into database.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50849) worked for me.

- Set your breakpoint in the extension
- Select Debug / Attach to Process by PID or name
- Enter the name of the extension target
- Trigger the push notification

Also make, sure you have set `"mutable-content" : 1` in your notification payload.

Comment: thanks for your replay, it is working now, actually problem was before executing NotificationExtension delegate my application remote notification delegate take places. so i just comment that line for some moment. and worked for me.